# What is a Mongoose model property that contains 'ref' but does not specify type?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Very new to Mongoose -- I'm working on an existing project and have been given the task of changing some model properties.  I understand that if a model contains a property of this type

```
postedBy: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User'
}
```

this property references another model/schema, and to get access to that linked model/schema one needs to `populate` it to gain access to this property.

But in the code I'm reviewing (which I didn't write) there are many properties of this type

```
contentTypes: [{ ref: 'ContentType' }],
source: { ref: 'Source',required: true },
```

where another schema is referenced, but there is no type.  Is this the same sort of relationship, and the `id` is implied? Is this a subdocument?

As an additional question: if in a model I wanted to refer to a property of a linked model (or schema), would I need to `populate` first?   That is, if it's a subdocument, I can just use dot notation, but if it is a "linked" document, I'm not sure.

Comment: Without type it throws error TypeError: Undefined type `Source` at `source.ref`. Seems to be an invalid schema definition. Are you able to run the code to create documents?

Comment: Yes -- this is a large project I've joined as a junior developer after a lot of the code has been written.  I believe I see the error of my ways in that all of these schemas are then being passed to a model "factory"  which sets the type os objectID, which I think takes care of it all -- I should have read further in the code.

Comment: Thus, in the model factory we have the following code snippet:

Comment: new: function(name, properties, statics, methods, schemaMods) {
    // Add default definition to properties with references and load reference schemas
    Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(key) {
      var modifiedProperty = (property) => {
        if (property.ref) {
          property.autopopulate = true;
          property.type = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
        }

        return property;
      };

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the model schemas do not stand on their own, but are passed to a model "factory", which gives them the property types they need.

Thus from that factory the following snippet (below).  I looked into the documentation for `mongoose-autopopulate`and I don't see what `autopopulate=true`means.

```
new: function(name, properties, statics, methods, schemaMods) {
// Add default definition to properties with references and load reference schemas
Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(key) {
  var modifiedProperty = (property) => {
    if (property.ref) {
      property.autopopulate = true;
      property.type = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
    }

    return property;
  };

  if (Array.isArray(properties[key]) && properties[key].length === 1) {
    properties[key][0] = modifiedProperty(properties[key][0]);
  } else {
    properties[key] = modifiedProperty(properties[key]);
  }
});
```